# How to get multiple row total by type

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the light of the code below, I want the return type to have a separate total and if the sales will be the result of the total sales input. In the meantime, the whole Total is going to Sales Total. Below are 2 roads as an example. There will be many more rows like this, each of which will have a type of sales / return. The following two inputs will fill up accordingly.

```js
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("input[name='qty[]']").each(function(index) {
        var qty = $("input[name='qty[]']").eq(index).val();
        var price = $("input[name='price[]']").eq(index).val();
        var total = parseFloat(parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price)).toFixed(2);
        if (!isNaN(total)) {
            $("input[name='sub_total[]']").eq(index).val(total);
            grandTotal = parseFloat(parseFloat(grandTotal) + parseFloat(total)).toFixed(2);
            $('#total').val(grandTotal);
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div onload="add_calcualte ()">
   <table border="1">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price </th>
            <th>Sub Total</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <select name='type[]'>
                  <option value="Sale"> Sale</> 
                  <option value="Retrun"> Retrun</> 
               </select>
            </td>
            <td><input name='product_name[]' value='Mobile' ></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='qty[]' class='qty' value='5'></td>
            <td><input type='number' name='price[]' class='price' value='15000'></td>
            <td><input type='number' name='sub_total[]' class='sub_total'></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <select name='type[]'>
                  <option value="Retrun"> Retrun</> 
                  <option value="Sale"> Sale</> 
               </select>
            </td>
            <td><input name='product_name[]' value='Headphone' ></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='qty[]' class='qty' value='1'></td>
            <td><input type='number' name='price[]' class='price' value='1200'></td>
            <td><input type='number' name='sub_total[]' class='sub_total'></td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
   </table>
   
   <br>
   Sales TOTAL: 
   <input class="form-control text-right" readonly type="text" id="total" name="total">
   <hr>
   Return TOTAL: 
   <input class="form-control text-right" readonly type="text" id="return" name="return">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function getTotals() {
  var total = $("select option[value=Sale]:selected").closest("tr").map(function() {
    return $(this).find(".sub_total").val()
  }).get().reduce((a, b) => {
    return +a + +b
  })
  $("#total").val(total)
  var _return = $("select option[value=Return]:selected").closest("tr").map(function() {
    return $(this).find(".sub_total").val()
  }).get().reduce((a, b) => {
    return +a + +b
  })
  $("#return").val(_return)
}
```

Also I assume `<option value="Retrun"> Retrun</>`  should be `<option value="Return"> Return</option>`

**Demo**

```js
$("input[name='qty[]']").each(function(index) {
  var qty = $("input[name='qty[]']").eq(index).val();
  var price = $("input[name='price[]']").eq(index).val();
  var total = parseFloat(parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price)).toFixed(2);
  if (!isNaN(total)) {
    $("input[name='sub_total[]']").eq(index).val(total);
    getTotals();
  }
})

function getTotals() {
  var total = $("select option[value=Sale]:selected").closest("tr").map(function() {
    return $(this).find(".sub_total").val()
  }).get().reduce((a, b) => {
    return +a + +b
  })
  $("#total").val(total)
  var _return = $("select option[value=Return]:selected").closest("tr").map(function() {
    return $(this).find(".sub_total").val()
  }).get().reduce((a, b) => {
    return +a + +b
  })
  $("#return").val(_return)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div onload="add_calcualte ()">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price </th>
        <th>Sub Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name='type[]'>
            <option value="Sale"> Sale
            </option>
            <option value="Return"> Retrun
            </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input name='product_name[]' value='Mobile'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='qty[]' class='qty' value='5'></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='price[]' class='price' value='15000'></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='sub_total[]' class='sub_total'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name='type[]'>
            <option value="Return"> Retrun
            </option>
            <option value="Sale"> Sale
            </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input name='product_name[]' value='Headphone'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='qty[]' class='qty' value='1'></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='price[]' class='price' value='1200'></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='sub_total[]' class='sub_total'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name='type[]'>
            <option value="Return"> Retrun
            </option>
            <option value="Sale"> Sale
            </option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input name='product_name[]' value='Headphone'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='qty[]' class='qty' value='1'></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='price[]' class='price' value='1200'></td>
        <td><input type='number' name='sub_total[]' class='sub_total'></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>

  <br> Sales TOTAL:
  <input class="form-control text-right" readonly type="text" id="total" name="total">
  <hr> Return TOTAL:
  <input class="form-control text-right" readonly type="text" id="return" name="return">
</div>
```

Comment: It's working pretty well. But once you select the return, if there is no return later, the total return is not 0.